# Difference between BigDecimal.ONE and new BigDecimal("1")

Tags: java

what is the difference between below two lines of code?

```
BigDecimal one = new BigDecimal("1");
BigDecimal two = BigDecimal.ONE;
```

Are both the lines same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

No, they're not quite the same - `new BigDecimal("1")` allocates a new object each time it's executed (and have to parse the value, too); `BigDecimal.ONE` will use a reference to the same existing object each time.

As `BigDecimal` is immutable, you can reuse an existing instance freely - so it makes sense to refer to a "pre-canned" object where you know what the value will be.

Comment: @Skeet:Thanks for your reply. functinality wise both are same right? if the method is executed. i mean both the lines produces same output.

Comment: @user1016403: They return references to *equal* objects, yes. But the difference could still be detectable. It depends on what you're doing with them.

Comment: @Skeet: i have a method. currently i am using BigDecimal one = new BigDecimal("1");. can i replace it with BigDecimal two = BigDecimal.ONE;.  will there be any impact? Thanks!

Comment: As Jon said, it depends on what you later do with them. If you do `a == b`, (i.e. identity comparison) then yes, your code will behave differently. If you only do `a.equals(b)`, then no.

Comment: @dty: I am not using both the lines.i will use any one of the line. will there be any impact?

Comment: @user1016403: You need to try to *understand* the comments here. If at any point you compare `BigDecimal` *references* directly, then yes, you'll see a change. Currently we have no idea what you do with the value. If you're using it sensibly, you shouldn't see any change other than less work being done.

Answer (score 7):

`BigDecimal.ONE` is a pre scanned object and its efficient in terms of memory utilization as compared to

```java
BigDecimal one = new BigDecimal("1");
```

because in this line it first creates an instance and then parses string `"1"` and then assigns.

whereas `BigDecimal.ONE` is like a constant and will give you direct value.

Hope this helps!